# How to use combobox selection as condition in IF statement

Tags: vb.net

I want to fill a data grid with data from ms access tables based on what is selected in the combobox. It has 4 choices. When I run the program and select a table from the dropdown, nothing happens.

Ive tried using breakpoints to see what is being passed through but still having no luck

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ComboBox1.SelectedIndexChanged
        If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            Me.TblCustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblCustomers)
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            Me.TblEmployeesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblEmployees)
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            Me.TblSalesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblSales)
        ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            Me.TblProductsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblProducts)
        End If
    End Sub
```

I expect the data grid to display data from the table i choose in the combo box.

Comment: Look for [DataGridView.DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.datasource?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_DataGridView_DataSource) property and how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Try to rebind your datagridview to the new data table after such as this:

```
    If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        Me.TblCustomersTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblCustomers)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblCustomers
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        Me.TblEmployeesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblEmployees)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblEmployees
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        Me.TblSalesTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblSales)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblSales
    ElseIf ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        Me.TblProductsTableAdapter.Fill(Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblProducts)
        DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.ProjectDatabaseDataSet.tblProducts()
    End If
```

I hope this can help you ^_^

Comment: It didn't work, but i can see why you suggested it.

Comment: Fixed it, If ComboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            DataGridView1.DataSource = Me.TblCustomersBindingSource